# C# Dividing Array Index Into Equal Parts

Tags: c#, arrays, intervals, division

I have an array of 1024 elements. Let's call it t[1024]. I want to choose an interval from this array index. Let's say index 100-240. How do I divide this interval index into 64 (relatively) equal parts? Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: What do you mean break it up, do you mean have 64 new arrays with the data at segments?

Comment: in my for cycle I need the following:
for(i=minInterval; i<=maxInterval, i<64; [with what value do i need to increase i?])

Comment: Can you add example of what your for loop would look like and where you would need this interval division? Having trouble understanding exactly what you mean.

Comment: My iteration would be i+=((maxInterval-minInterval)/64) Thanks for the help!

Comment: Since all values are ints (maxInterval-minInterval)/64 will give you varying results. If interval is less than 64 it will give 0 and get stuck in infinite loop. We need some idea of what you want to use this for so we can help. Lets say you have originalIndex, segment and segmentIndex variables how would you use them in your code?

Comment: I have an array of 1024 elements. With 2 trackbars I choose the interval I want, let's say (min)100-(max)240. I always check if the interval is more than 64 or equal to 64 so that it doesn't get stuck in a loop. I get varying int result, but I don't need it to be so accurate. I need it for a Spectrum Analyzer project.